# How to show download iPhone application on top of browser

Tags: html, browser, mobile-safari

What is the best way to show a button at the top of a browser requesting the user to download the iPhone application if they want?  Is there a plugin already made, or just a test for the user agent, and show this in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari provides a built-in way to do this: [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).